# Can I run scripts when a Xcode build process is aborted?

Tags: xcode

My build scripts update the Info.plist when the configuration is "debug".

It copies the original plist before updating the plist.

```bash
cp Info.plist Info.plist.temp
```

Then, it restores the original plist when a build process is finished.

```bash
mv -f Info.plist.temp Info.plist
```

But, when a build is aborted, the plist is not restored.  So I am wondering if I can run scripts to clean up when a build process is aborted.

Comment: Should I update Preprocessed-Info.plist instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can change properties of the Info.plist without updating the original file.

1. Enable `Preprocess Info.plist File` in the build settings.
2. Add build scripts in `Build Phases`, that update `${TEMP_DIR}/Preprocessed-Info.plist`.
3. Set `${TEMP_DIR}/Preprocessed-Info.plist` to `Input Files` field of the build script.